# Adding string before sys.stdout.write in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

How do i add string or text before sys.stdout.write.

```
for i in range(101):
        time.sleep(0.60)
        sys.stdout.write("\r%d%%" % i)
        sys.stdout.flush()
```

The above code prints only percentage like this :
 50%

I want to add text before percentage which should be in a single line like below:

PERCENTAGE COMPLETED : 50%

Please help me.

Comment: What's wrong with sys.stdout.write("blah blah: %d%%\r" % i)

Answer (score 0):

Why not...

```
for i in range(101):
        time.sleep(0.60)
        sys.stdout.write("\rPERCENTAGE COMPLETED %d%%" % i)
        sys.stdout.flush()
```

Though it's not clear to me why you are using sys.stdout.write() instead of print()

Comment: Thank you, i was actually trying to pass the string or text using .format and the argument as 'text', your answer works very well.